# Sending text from PHP-created HTML

Tags: php, html

I have some text that I get from the database like this:

```
$solution = $row['solution'];
```

Then I have some HTML I create in PHP using that variable like this:

```
echo '<a class="delete_suggested_solution" data-problem_id="'.$problem_id.'" data-suggested_solution_id="'.$suggested_solution_id.'" href="#">Delete</a> | <a href="#" class="edit_suggested_solution" data-problem_id="'.$problem_id.'" data-suggested_solution_id="'.$suggested_solution_id.'" data-solution_text="'.$solution.'" data-solution_title="'.$solution_name.'">Edit</a>';
```

That actually works fine in most cases, but when the $solution has a link in it like this `<a href="http://SomeUrlWhatever.com">something</a>` then this HTML breaks the HTML on the page when it is displayed.

Is there something that can be done so that the HTML on the page does not become broken for me?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the part you want here is `something` and not the link, just use [`strip_tags()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) and [`htmlentities()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to retrieve only the tag's inner text content, and encode quotes to be used inside HTML attributes.

```
$solution = htmlentities(strip_tags($row['solution']), ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: thanks - trying it now.  What about when actually displaying the text? Should I use the functions you suggest? Or should I not "massage" any of that text?

Comment: @GeekedOut If you're just displaying it and it originated as user input, use `htmlspecialchars()` to encode it against cross site scripting attacks.

Comment: what are cross-site scripting attacks? I mean - what do they do to my forms?

Comment: @GeekedOut see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting They make it possible for malicious users to run javascript against other users on your site, potentially modifying your site's content or launching drive by downloads.